# Replacing JavaFX BarChart in a Stack Pane

Tags: user-interface, javafx, combobox, javafx-8, bar-chart

I have a JavaFX Stack Pane that contains three objects: a `Button`, a `BarChart<String, ? extends Number>`, and a `ComboBox`. The data displayed in the chart is dependent on the current selection of the ComboBox. On the event that another option is selected in the ComboBox, I would like to reload the chart's data and automatically display the updated chart. Is there an easy way to replace/update the chart that is in my Stack Pane with the new chart?

Comment: Why do you need a new chart? Why not just replace the data in the existing chart?